# VB.NET how to insert data in WebClient() request

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am new to consuming web services. I am trying to sent a POST request to a web service from a VB.NET console application. I'm told I need to include the data, but not passed a variable in the URL, which I know how to do.
The following cURL command worked(before I removed most of the bearer token, the order contents, and the true web address for security reasons).
The web service is in an unknown language.

How do I insert the --data portion in VB?

curl --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIU..." --data '{"order":{"content":"file_version:1.0\r\nstart_order\r\n ... \r\nend_order\r\n"}}'  https://someURL/api/push_order

The commented code below is one of the other options I tried in addition to sending the --data et the end of the URL .../api/push_order/?orderString which also produced an error.

```
Dim server as String = "https://<someURL>"
Dim url as String = ""       
Using client As New WebClient()
     client.Headers("Content-Type") = "application/json"
     client.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " + BearerToken

    'Dim orderInBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(orderInfo) + "'")
     Dim orderString As String = "'" + (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(orderInfo) + "'"
     url = String.Format("{0}/api/push_order", server)

    'client.UploadData(url, "POST", orderInBytes)
    ''This returns "'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'"
    client.UploadString(url, "POST", orderString)

End Using
```

I expect the VB code to work the same as the curl command.

Comment: I edited the code snippet to put back the opening single quote added to the JSON string. I accidentally deleted it when posting the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question but this may be helpful to someone else someday.

Not sure why I got down voted but no matter...

When I finally got the author of the web service to send me the server log, from my attempts to post, it was instantly clear what the problem was. He had told me that I needed to enclose my JSON package in " ' " single quotes which I did. .NET then added quotes as well resulting in the JSON being enclosed in doubled single quotes.
The line, in the (edited)snippet in my original question, to create the JSON data string should have read:

Dim orderString As String = (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(orderInfo)